# How can I run cron every 2 days ensuring no overlaps at end of month

Tags: cron

I have a script that takes 25 hours to finish and I have to ensure it will not overlap.
Normally I would just use `*/2` in cron to ensure running every two days, but that script will run both `31` and `1` day of the month causing overlapping (also 29 february).
Starting on second day won't help since I need that script to run on first day of each month.

How can I tell cron to skip last day of month if its odd?